# Java: how to write short array like a byte array in a file

Tags: java, file, arrays

I want to add this table in a file:

```
public static final short[] FMW = {0x18, 0xC1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0xC1, 0x00}
```

I need to use a short array, because 0xC1 value is not recognized like a byte.

Then, I want to put this array in my file:

```
DataOutputStream out = null;
try {
   out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
   for (short anInt : FMW)
      out.write((byte)anInt);
   out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
...
```

But when I read this file content after that, it's not correct:

```
try {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
  if (file.length() < offset+count) count = (int)(file.length() - offset);
  char[] rawdata = new char[count];
  reader.read(rawdata, 0, FMW.length);
  ...
```

My rawdata contains:

```
[0] : 0x18
[1] : 0xFFFD
[2] : 0x00
[3] : 0x00
[4] : 0x36
[5] : 0xFFFD
[6] : 0x00
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a similar type of problem then I have written a method that takes a `short[]` array and returns a `byte[]` array -

```
public byte[] shortToByte(short[] shortInts) {
    int j=0;
    int length=shortInts.length;
    byte[] byteData=new byte[length*2];
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
      byteData[j++]=(byte)(shortInts[i]>>>8);
      byteDataj++]=(byte)(shortInts[i]>>>0);
    }
    return byteData;
  }
```

Comment: No, the problem stills the same: I have 0xFFFD instead to have 0xC1 in my case.